# How to correctly tailor a fluent builder

Tags: c#, api, builder, fluent

I'm creating a helper class which should guide my co-workers in using it. Let's assume its a string-builder for proper building of a markdown-string.

```
string result = new OwnStringBuilder()
            .NewTable()
                .Tablehead("head1")
                .Tablehead("head2")
                .TableheadEnding()
                .Tablecontent("content1")
                .Tablecontent("content2")
                .TableNextLine()
                .Tablecontent("content3")
                .Tablecontent("content4")
            .EndTable()
```

It works properly as intended but I want to restrict the possibilities of the user.
When typing `.NewTable.` it shows all possible methods like Tablehead, TableheadEnding, Tablecontent, TableNextLine and EndTable.
I hope there is a way to restrict the `table` to use just the method `tablehead`.
The `Tablehead` just to use either another `Tablehead` or the `TableheadEnding` and so on.

The table itself is created via

```
public OwnStringBuilder NewTable()
    {
        return new OwnStringBuilder(this, StringBuilder.AppendLine());
    }
```

and e.g. the Tablehead via

```
public OwnStringBuilderTableHelper Tablehead(string content)
    {
        StringBuilder.Append(content);
        return this;
    }
```

I've already googled but it's already rare to get good examples for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it using Interfaces.

Each method only shows and allows the methods that are declared in the interface.

```cs
// only Head() function is allowed
internal interface ITable
{
    ITableHead Head(string value);
}

// it allows Head(), Content() and End() functions.
internal interface ITableHead
{
    ITableHead Head(string value);
    ITableHead Content(string value);
    ITable End();
}
```

This is your table class, that implements all interfaces:

```cs
internal class MyTable : ITable, ITableHead
{
    public MyTable() { }

    public ITableHead Head(string value)
    {
        // add value
        return (ITableHead)this;
    }

    public ITableHead Content(string value)
    {
        // add value
        return (ITableHead)this;
    }

    public ITable End()
    {
        // some op
        return this;
    }
}
```

And that's the builder:

```cs
internal class MyTableBuilder 
{
    private MyTable _myTable;

    public static ITable CreateTable()
    {
        return new MyTable();
    }

    public ITableHead Head(string value)
    {
        // add data
        return _myTable.Head(value);
    }

    public ITableHead Content(string value)
    {
        // add data
        return _myTable.Content(value);
    }

    public ITable End()
    {
        return _myTable.End();
    }
}
```

Now you can build a class in that way:

```cs
var t = MyTableBuilder.CreateTable()
            .Head("head1")
            .Head("head2")
            .Content("content")
            .End();
```

You could even hide MyTable declaring it inside the builder:

Answer (score 0):

As with any class, the only way to restrict what methods are callable is to explicitly define those as public methods.

If you only want certain methods available, don't return `OwnStringBuilder`, but rather create specific classes for tables, table heads, table contents, etc, each with their own end methods that would return back to some outer content builder, or just `OwnStringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

It is common for elements on a builder to accept a `Func<SubBuilder>` which is used to build upon the nested elements

For example, [QuestPdf](https://github.com/QuestPDF/QuestPDF) has tables that look like this:

```
container
    .Padding(10)
    .Table(table =>
    {
        table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
        {
            columns.RelativeItem();
            columns.RelativeItem();
        });

        table.Cell().Text("Hello");
        table.Cell().Text("world!");
    });
```

And my own email templating builder looks like:

```
EmailBuilder.Create<ConfirmEmailConfiguration>(config => config.Subject,
        config => config.EmailColours)
    .Add(topLevel => topLevel.Container
        .Add(container => container.Header(config => config.Header))
        .Add(container => container.HeroImage(config => config.HeroImage))
        .Add(container => container.OneColumn()
            .Add(column => column.Block()
                .Add(block => block.Title(config => config.Column1Title))
                .Add(block => block.Paragraph(config => config.Column1Paragraph)))
            .Add(column => column.Block()
                .Add(block => block.Button(config => config.Column1ConfirmEmailButton)))
            .Add(column => column.Block()
                .Add(block => block.Paragraph(config => config.Column1Paragraph2)))))
    .Add(topLevel => topLevel.Footer(config => config.Footer))
    .Build();
```

Answer (score -1):

- One approach requires you to define separate `readonly struct` types (which encapsulate and hide the real mutable builder) which expose **only the subset of valid and possible actions for a given builder's state**.
- The advantage of using `readonly struct` types is that they effectively have zero runtime cost (as they don't incur GC allocation).
- You'd also might need extension-methods on your `OwnStringBuilder`.
- Though you won't get any context-sensitive indentation. C# doesn't currently have a way to indicate to editors how to indent builder chains.

Here's a simple demo example:

```cs
public static class OwnStringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static TableBuilder CreateTable( this OwnStringBuilder inner )
    {
        return new TableBuilder( inner );
    }
}

public readonly struct TableBuilder
{
    private readonly OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder;

    internal TableBuilder( OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder )
    {
        this.innerBuilder = innerBuilder;
    }

    //

    public TableHeadBuilder TableHead( String name )
    {
        this.innerBuilder.AddTableHead( name );
        return new TableHeadBuilder( this.innerBuilder );
    }

    public TableBodyBuilder TableBody( String name )
    {
        this.innerBuilder.AddTableHead( name );
        return new TableBodyBuilder( this.innerBuilder );
    }
}

public readonly struct TableHeadBuilder
{
    private readonly OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder;

    internal TableHeadBuilder( OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder )
    {
        this.innerBuilder = innerBuilder;
    }

    //

    public TableHeadBuilder ColumnHeader( String name )
    {
        this.innerBuilder.AddColumnHeader( name );
        return this;
    }
    
    public TableBuilder Done()
    {
        return new TableBuilder( this.innerBuilder );
    }
}

public readonly struct TableBodyBuilder
{
    private readonly OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder;

    internal TableBodyBuilder( OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder )
    {
        this.innerBuilder = innerBuilder;
    }

    //

    public TableBodyBuilder Row( params Object?[] values )
    {
        this.innerBuilder.AddRow( values );
        return this;
    }
    
    public TableBuilder Done()
    {
        return new TableBuilder( this.innerBuilder );
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```cs
OwnStringBuilder sb = new OwnStringBuilder();

sb.CreateTable()
    .TableHead()
        .ColumnHeader( "foo" )
        .ColumnHeader( "bar" )
        .ColumnHeader( "baz" )
        .Done()
    .TableBody()
        .Row( "a", 123, 0.99M )
        .Row( "a", 123, 0.99M )
        .Row( "a", 123, 0.99M )
        .Done()
    .Done();
```

My example design above isn't perfect: there's actually a design-bug: after `TableHeadBuilder.Done()` is called you get back a `TableBuilder` object, which doesn't stop you from calling `.TableHead()` a second time, or even after writing the `TableBody()`, which is incorrect (as generally a table can't have more than 1 header, and a header does not follow a body).

i.e. you _could do this, which is silly, if not incorrect:

```cs
sb.CreateTable()
    .TableHead()
        .ColumnHeader( "foo" )
        .Done()
    .TableHead()
        .ColumnHeader( "bar" )
        .ColumnHeader( "baz" )
        .Done()
    .TableBody()
        .Row( "a", 123, 0.99M )
        .Row( "a", 123, 0.99M )
        .Done()
    .TableHead()
        .ColumnHeader( "foo" )
        .Done()
    .Done();
```

That *is* fixable though, but requires more careful thought to [think of the builder as a finite-state-machine and carefully design each struct to prevent invalid state transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). One way to do this would be to return a `struct TableBuilderForBodyOnly` from `TableHeadBuilder.Done()` instead of `TableBuilder`, and `TableBuilderForBodyOnly` would not have a `.TableHead()` method. *Voila*.

```cs
public readonly struct TableHeadBuilder
{
    // etc, the same as above except for `Done`:

   
    public TableBuilderForBodyOnly Done()
    {
        return new TableBuilderForBodyOnly( this.innerBuilder );
    }
}

public readonly struct TableBuilderForBodyOnly
{
    private readonly OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder;

    internal TableBuilderForBodyOnly( OwnStringBuilder innerBuilder )
    {
        this.innerBuilder = innerBuilder;
    }

    // 

    public TableBodyBuilder TableBody( String name )
    {
        this.innerBuilder.AddTableHead( name );
        return new TableBodyBuilder( this.innerBuilder );
    }
}
```

So now *it's impossible* to render a second `TableHead` after the first table-head has been written. *Neat, huh?*